# Convert SQL procedure to function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

```
create function fiyathesapla(@StartDate datetime2(5),@EndDate datetime2(5),@kodu nvarchar(max))
returns table
as
return (

WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
     )
SELECT SUM( v_period.fiyat-((v_period.fiyat/100)*v_period.indirim))  FROM theDates,v_period  WHERE tarih1<=theDates.theDate and tarih2>=theDates.theDate  and  vkodu=@kodu
)
go
```

---Error code---

> Msg 4514, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fiyathesapla, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
> CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1.

I get this error when trying to create a function.
It helps to calculate the price by counting the two entered dates days by days.
but when I create the stored procedure it works.
I want to create a Function, how can I edit it.

---Procedure code that works properly---

```
USE [villapaket1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[FN_fiyat]    Script Date: 30.09.2020 16:18:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FN_fiyat] @StartDate datetime2(5),@EndDate datetime2(5),@kodu nvarchar(max)
AS

WITH theDates AS
    (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
       FROM theDates
      WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
    )
SELECT SUM( v_period.fiyat-((v_period.fiyat/100)*v_period.indirim))  FROM theDates,v_period  WHERE tarih1<=theDates.theDate and tarih2>=theDates.theDate  and  vkodu=@kodu
```

Comment: Your code is not MySQL.  It looks like SQL Server, so I added that tag.

Comment: Looks like the database engine is telling you that `SUM( v_period.fiyat-((v_period.fiyat/100)*v_period.indirim))` (= the first column of the final `select`) needs an alias. This is not required to show the results outside a function, but it _is_ required to return a table with valid column names.

Comment: The problem is here "WITH theDates AS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the database engine is telling you that `SUM( v_period.fiyat-((v_period.fiyat/100)*v_period.indirim))` (= the first column of the final select) needs an alias. This is not required to show the results outside a function, but it *is* required to return a table with valid column names.

Issue reproduction with small data set and easy (but similar) function below and in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8cca1fd8dde87461d7d1cf302b2b830f).

**Sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  id int
);

insert into MyTable (id) values
(100), (101), (102);
```

**Selection**

```
with cte as
(
  select id-100 as NewId from MyTable
)
select sum(cte.NewId) --> no column alias, works fine (result table has unnamed column)
from cte;
```

**Function**

```
create function MyFunction()
returns table
as return
(
  with cte as
  (
    select id-100 as NewId from MyTable
  )
  select sum(cte.NewId) --> no column alias, does NOT work
  from cte
);
```

> CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1.

Updated to working function:

```
create function MyFunction()
returns table
as return
(
  with cte as
  (
    select id-100 as NewId from MyTable
  )
  select sum(cte.NewId) as IdSum --> with column alias
  from cte
);
```